# Is it possible to get the Id of a record in an component without using extension for the parent VF page?

Tags: visualforce-component

I have a visualforce component with a controller. This component is used in a VF page with a standard controller. This Vf would be an inline page in different objects making it reusable. How should I get the record's Id to the component's controller without using an extension for the VF page?

Comment: Using component's attributes (`apex:attribute`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this.  ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');
This works, just checked. 
-Akash

Comment: This breaks the modularity of the component controller and would create a dependency in the controller that an Id value is passed across the URL of the containing page. Ok for a POC, but I would hesitate to put it into production that way.

Answer (score 1):

You would need an attribute in the component that you pass the id value into. Let's say you had a component called MyComponent as below:

```
<apex:component controller="MyController">
  <apex:attribute name="recId" assignTo="{!myId}" type="Id"/>
  ...
```

In the component attribute declaration above, the `assignTo` parameter allows you to bind the value passed into the attribute to a setter or property in the controller.

Then in your component controller you would have the property that you are binding to:

```
public class MyController {
  public Id myId {get;set;}
...
```

Then in your VF page, bind the field value of standard controller to the attribute you've just declared above as such:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" ...>
  ...
  <c:MyComponent recId="{!Account.id}" />
```

This will have the effect of passing the value into the component, it will invoke the setter in the component controller, and your component controller will have access to the value from the containing page.

An advantage of this approach is that you are not dependent on standard controller. Your component will have an expected parameter that you can bind *any* Id value to. If you simply request the page URL parameter, if someone attempts to use this component in another context, it could break.

You might want to read a bit about the order of [execution when rendering VF pages](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_lifecycle.htm) to better understand the mechanics of how this works.

(disclaimer: freehand code above...mistakes might be all over the place)

Comment: I tried this with a custom object, and it doesn't appear to work...

Comment: I threw together an example at this gist. Maybe I'll update my answer.  https://gist.github.com/pchittum/fa8f3097c0c82ad8e4ae

Comment: My mistake - This [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23696616/how-to-auto-call-function-in-visualforce-page-without-using-javascript) by @Eyescream clariefied my error - I was using the attribute value of Id in the constructor.  I've had to use callbacks to execute DMLs in the past, and I should have thought about it...  Oops!

Answer (score 1):

Use ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id') in the component controller to get the record ID.

Answer (score 0):

Khusboo,

You want to create a generic component which will work for more then one object, then you cant use standard controller and you have to use controller, not controller extension .

In this case you can't get objects id in the page .

But if your component is for only one object like for Account, then you can use Account as a standard Controller and then you can get Id like this

```
{!Id}
```

But if your stick to make it generic, you must use controller to make it work smooth.

Let me know if you need more help regarding this.

Mark this as a answer if it solve your problem.